# Can't access object created in NSXMLParserDelegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I am using an NSXMParser to read XML from a server.  I've set an NSXMLParserDelegate and in the didStartElement method, I do the following

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser
        didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
        namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
        qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    NSNumber * tempNumber = [elements objectForKey:elementName];

    elementType = [tempNumber intValue]; ;

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"recipe"])
    {
        [recipes addObject:[[Recipe alloc] init]];
    }
}
```

*recipes* is an NSMutableArray member variable that is initialized in a non-delegate method.  I then try to access the *Recipe* object in the *recipes* array in the 
foundCDATA method:

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser
    foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{

    NSError * error=nil;
    NSString * encodedString, * decodedString, * tempString;
    NSData * decodedData, * decodedData1;
    NSLog(@"recipes size %d", [recipes count]);
    Recipe * rcp = [recipes lastObject]; 

    ...
}
```

The NSLog shows that the *recipes* NSMutableArray has one item in it, but *rcp* always ends up nil.  Can anyone suggest why that is and if there is a way to rework this code so that I can modify the *Recipe* objects I put the *recipes* array?

Thanks,

Jason Mazzotta

Comment: Make sure your Xcode schema is set to debug. In release mode Xcode will not de-symbolise the var.

Comment: `NSLog(@"recipes size %d", [recipes count]);Recipe * rcp = [recipes lastObject];NSLog(@"%@", rcp);` Do you mean the rcp here is nil with `[recipes count]` equals to 1?

Comment: Hi KoduCC.  Yes, rcp is nil when [recipes count] equals 1.